# Why am I getting multiple outputs with this decorated function?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I've recently made a move from C/C++ to Python. Having difficulties in understanding closures and decorators.

Declared the functions as such (an online blog had this piece code as an example)

```
def outer(some_func):
    def inner():
        print "Before Foo"
        ret = some_func()
        return ret + 1

    return inner

def foo():
    return 1
```

When I run the following code once

```
foo = outer(foo)
foo()
```

I get the expected output as

```
Before Foo
2
```

However if I run it more than once, I get strange output. I do not understand what happens.

```
# Writing it down twice instead of running the same cell 
# twice on my IPython notebook to better explain things here
foo = outer(foo)
foo = outer(foo)    
foo()
```

The output is as follows

```
Before Foo
Before Foo
3
```

Why do I get 3 as the output and why does "Before Foo" get printed twice?

Edit:- What happens when I decorate the function again? Running foo = outer(foo) is quite clear now. What happens when I run foo = outer(foo) again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're decorating the decorated function again. `outer` takes in a function and returns closure which of course is function by itself. There's nothing preventing you to pass the returned function as a parameter to the following call like you're doing in your example.

If you change your code to print the function being called and return value it's easier to understand what's going on:

```
def outer(some_func):
    def inner():
        print "Before inner, func: {0}".format(some_func)
        ret = some_func()
        print "After inner, return: {0}".format(ret + 1)
        return ret + 1

    return inner

def foo():
    return 1

foo = outer(foo)
foo = outer(foo)
foo()
```

Output:

```
Before inner, func: <function inner at 0x7f1924b516e0>
Before inner, func: <function foo at 0x7f1924b51668>
After inner, return: 2
After inner, return: 3
```

Comment: What happens when I run foo = outer(foo) again? I don't understand as to why does it output 3. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal: I've changed the example a bit, maybe that helps. Anyway when you run `foo = outer(foo)` for the first time it will wrap the original `foo` and returns a function whose return value is `foo() + 1` which is `2`. It will also assign the returned function to variable `foo` thus hiding your original function. The second `foo = outer(foo)` then wraps the function again adding `1` to the result thus the end result is `3`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider what `foo` refers to in each statement of `foo=outer(foo)`. Initially you define foo to be a function that always returns 1. Once you call `foo=outer(foo)` though, it now has a new value. Try to imagine replacing the foo on the right side of the assignment with what foo would equal before you run that line. Remember, you're nesting functions here.

A couple ways that might help you wrap your head around what's happening are

1. Add a couple more print statements to different parts of your function to help understand what's being called and when.
2. Don't re-assign to the variable foo unless there is a reason to do so. Maybe choose foo1, foo2, etc. so you can look back to previous iterations of foo and see more clearly the composition that's taking place.

Answer (score 0):

question hoebenkr, I don't understand how when you're assigning the variable ret to the parameter of the function, you **call** the function. Is that the de-facto standard for declaring a variable to a function? It promptly runs in python?